# Python ModuleNotFoundError '~' M1 Macbook

Tags: python, module, package

I think every time I install something with pip, it  returns 'ModuleNotFoundError'. No error occurred when installing with brew. My python is installed opt/homebrew/bin. As far as I know, python is automatically installed usr/bin.

Is that the reason? Is this an M1 chip issue?

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message? Also, make sure you use `/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3`

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I did and it worked!